# how to map the message from webservice call to the database in mule?

Tags: mule

I'm using mule to expose a webservice for salesforce to call. My questions is how to map the elements from wsdl to my target mysql database?
e.g: in the wsdl file, I have these:

```
<xsd:element name="createAccount">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="accountName" type="xsd:string" nillable="false"/>
<xsd:element name="accountType" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="industry" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Then I want to use a DataMapper to map these three elements to the three fields in MySQL table. My question is:
1. In DataMappper, if I choose XML as the input, it will ask for the schema file which I don't have. Then how can I configure this in DataMapper?

2. What to write in Database connect? Suppose the field names in my sql server table is name, type and industry. How can I write the insert statement?

Thank you.

Viv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You do have the schema, as you have pasted a portion of it in the question. Find [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/XML-only+SOAP+Web+Service+Example) an example of Datamapper and SOAP.
2. Datamapper will know where to map if you use the new database connector rather than the old jdbc, see this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fmFescqdao

Comment: Thanks Victor, but the first example seems not available.